# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel "http://www.rtvs.sk/televizia/archiv"

Tags: c#, ssl

I am very new to ssl/tls, so please be patient. The code works for me few months for another sites (iprima.cz for example), but dont working for rtvs.sk.
it writes: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
I have tried everything, but nothing works. Please help me.

```
string url1 = "https://www.rtvs.sk/televizia/archiv";
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)(0xc0 | 0x300 | 0xc00);
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
//It is because I have tried enerything
            string rets = "";
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Proxy = null;

                int i = 0;
            zatry:

                try
                {
                    Stream stream = wc.OpenRead(url1);
                    Encoding kod = Encoding.UTF8;
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, kod);
                    rets = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
```

It seems to me to be site-specific, it works on Opera and other browsers, but not on my code.
It maybe a simple thing, but after reviewing all solutions for 5 hours and nothing works, I need a help. Thank you very much

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.03062SP1Rel

It has the same error on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and 2019 version 16.4.3

Comment: Very dangerous and chaotic `ServicePointManager` setup. What Framework version is targeted by the project?

Comment: I added answers to your question to the end of my question. Thank you

Comment: I'm not about the installed .NET Framework version, I'm about targeted: Open project properties in Visual Studio, navigate to Application tab and tell the value of `Target framework` selector. I'm asking because I cannot reproduce, the code works on my side.

Comment: Net framework 4 Client Profie

Comment: Net framework 4.7.2 has the same error

Comment: Cannot reproduce neither for 4 Client Profile, nor for 4.7.2. Is support of Windows XP critical for you?

Comment: I don´t need a support of WinXP. I am on Win7

Comment: If it works on your computer, then it is something on my PC's. Because I tried it on two my laptops. Do you have any idea what it should be?

Comment: What kind of app are you using? Winforms, Console, etc.? What method calls the page loading? Event Handler? Could you show that method? It needed for the most correct answer which I'm preparing now.

Comment: To ensure that problem is on your PC or not, open in Visual Studio menu `Build -> Batch Build`, check all checkboxes there and press `Clean` button. Then launch the app again. Sometimes Visual Studio doesn't rebuild the app properly. This action may solve that. The above questions are still actual.

Comment: I am ready to send you all my program - but i cant see how to do it. Could you send me your email adress?

Comment: No it didnt help.

Comment: I have the same problem (Win7 and Win10). My application was running (23. August 2020) and now it does not work (identical binary file). Nothing helped (nor any update in `ServicePointManager` nor anything other fix for "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS" that I could find). My last hope was disabling antivirus (Eset Internet Security), but simple "disable" does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

It seems like the https://www.rtvs.sk/ server uses a not standard way of communication, that is not supported in .NET Framework libraries.

The server redirects any HTTP connection to HTTPS connection and this can not be avoided.

To bypass the "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error you need to use a different HTTPS client. And I do not mean use the `WebRequest.Create` instead of the `WebClient`. The error is still here as this was the code I used in my application. A communication error is probably somewhere deeper in system since even Internet Explorer does not open the page (at least not in Windows 7).

There are a few possible options of an alternate client:

1. Write your own client from scratch - I cannot recommend this solution, it is hard, prone to errors...
2. Buy an existing alternative client - I found only one alternative HTTPS client for C# and the price was high. Too much for my simple personal application.
3. Use an alternative external client - e.g. `wget`, or an other downloader (custom and/or existing).
4. Try to use the application from Linux (or Mono framework). I did not test this solution but it is (at least theoretically) possible that the problem can be solved this way.

### My Solution

After a simple test I found out, that there is no problem when downloading using Python. So I made a simple Python downloader and use it from my C# application.

The code in C# is:

```
private const string PythonSciptPath = "PythonDownloader.py";

private static bool UseStandardDownloader(string address) =>
    !address.StartsWith("https://www.rtvs.sk/", StringComparison.Ordinal);

private static byte[] GetData(string address)
{
    var start = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "python.exe",
        Arguments = PythonSciptPath + " \"" + address + "\"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    string result;
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return Convert.FromBase64String(result);
}
```

The code in Python (the "PythonDownloader.py" file) is:

```
import base64
import sys
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
stream = opener.open(sys.argv[1])

while True:
    contentBytes = stream.read(60)
    if len(contentBytes) == 0:
        break

    contentbase64Bytes = base64.b64encode(contentBytes)
    contentString = contentbase64Bytes.decode("UTF-8")
    print(contentString)
```

A simple way how to work with this is to add the file to project and select "Copy to output directory" option to "Copy if newer".

The current simple solution the code does not handle any error. I leave that part to you.

I also tried to use IronPython, but the simple client I wrote did not work because of a missing library. And it is possible that it will not work because it uses the .NET Framework libraries as interpreter.